# 404 Error on single ASP.Net 2.0 page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Question from a rookie...

I'm maintaining a legacy application that was developed by a third party years ago.

I'm modifying source code in VS2017. Everything builds properly and if I debug from local IIS Express it works fine.

However, after publishing the site and copying the entire IIS directory, I have a single (sub) page returning a 404 error. The rest of the site works fine, but the page I've actually modified is broken. Using IIS 6.0 on 2008R2 with the website being precompiled. I've scanned through what logs I'm familiar with and can't really find anything.

Any hints on where I'd look to find the issue? Do I need to attach a remote debugger?

Comment: Impossible to say. *Maybe* a look at what you changed will give a clue. Make sure the precompiled page directive (App_Web_ ...) matches the dll name (if compiling pages separately).

Comment: I upgraded the site to .NET 4.5.2 and it works now...

Comment: Should probably delete this question if you can.